# Fluster 2 how to show all markers at a specific zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using fluster 2 to cluster markers and have found that the fluster clustering method is overly aggressive. So that even when I am zoomed in to city level I still end up having a lot more clusters than I really want. Does anyone know how to modify the fluster .js to make it show all markers once you get down to say zoom level 5?

There is a bit too much code relating to fluster to add here, so this question is more for people who already use fluster for their marker clustering needs.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

you can make a listener on the zoom level of your map and then control the clusters. this an example of what probably your code shoud look like. I havent tested the code , the comple tutorial from which i took the code is [here](http://codesnipp.it/javascript/google-maps-v3-with-fancybox-clustering).

```
var fluster = new Fluster2(map);
// Set styles for the clustered icons
fluster.styles = {
  0: {
    image: "http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/images/m1.png",
    textColor: "#FFFFFF",
    width: 53,
    height: 52
  },
  10: {
    image: "http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/images/m2.png",
    textColor: "#FFFFFF",
    width: 56,
    height: 55
  },
  15: {
    image: "http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/1.0/images/m3.png",
    textColor: "#FFFFFF",
    width: 66,
    height: 65
  }
};
// Initialize Fluster
// This will set event handlers on the map and calculate clusters the first time.
fluster.initialize();

// Event listener for switching to Street View/Road Map to show/hide the
// close button, respectively
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama,"visible_changed",toggleVisible);

// Add a listener to the zoom change event so we can change the grid size
// of the cluster script. Should be dynamic!
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {

  var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

  switch(true){
    case zoomLevel > 13:
      fluster.gridSize = 0;
      break;
    case zoomLevel > 12:
      fluster.gridSize = 10;
      break;
    case zoomLevel > 7:
      fluster.gridSize = 20;
      break;
    case zoomLevel > 5:
      fluster.gridSize = 40;
      break;
    default:
      fluster.gridSize = 60;
      break;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer Zied.

BTW if you have multiple markers with the same position, the clustering will still happen even though the gridSize is 0. 
To get around this set the grid to -1

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {

  var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

  switch(true){
    case zoomLevel > 13:
      fluster.gridSize = -1;
          break;
    case zoomLevel > 12:
      fluster.gridSize = 10;
      break;
    case zoomLevel > 7:
      fluster.gridSize = 20;
      break;
    case zoomLevel > 5:
      fluster.gridSize = 40;
      break;
    default:
      fluster.gridSize = 60;
      break;
  }

});
```